# Publishing option is not available for one content type in drupal

Tags: drupal

I have drupal 6.25. I have some content types like article, editors, slideshow and others.
publishing options are listed normally for all content types except "article" (although i gave "administer nodes" permission to my editors). i have tried some modules like [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) but i still have the same problem for this content type for all users (of course except the admin user, admin can see it normally).
any idea of what might cause this and how to fix it?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think one of your modules have some hardcode for publishing options of contetn type that it provide. To fix it you need to loock into code of modules, or disable installed modules one by step and check results. If you know what module can affect permissions of certain content type - you can look at issues queue of this module. Maybe it have a bug related to permissios, or wrong form alter depended of role.